# How to prove $\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{M - 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^m}{c_{(m)}}}}{{m!}}} > 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How to prove $\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{M - 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^m}{c_{(m)}}}}{{m!}}}  > 0$? Here, ${c_{(m)}} = c\left( {c - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {c - m + 1} \right)$ and $0<c<1$.

Comment: Out of curiosity: where did this come from?

Comment: ${c\choose m}$ is a standard notation for $\frac{c(c-1)\cdots (c-m+1)}{m!}$, where $m$ is an integer and $c$ can be any complex number.

Comment: @pigeon, Thanks a lot, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_identity) and induction on $M$, one can show that
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{M}(-1)^m\binom{c}{m}=(-1)^M\binom{c-1}{M}.
$$
Since
$$
(-1)^M\binom{c-1}{M}=\frac{(1-c)(2-c)\cdots(M-c)}{M!}
$$
and $c<1$, each factor is positive and thus so is the product.